# Facebook Messenger Bot blank response

Tags: php, facebook, bots, messenger

I've just stumbled upon messenger bot and felt like doing myself one too.
I've setuped webhooks correctly, verified my webhook script and made myself a temporary simple thing to see the request when I send message to my bot.

```
<?php
$file = "data.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$data = $current ."\n". json_encode($_REQUEST);
file_put_contents ( $file , $data  );
```

It works (catches all the requests), but whenewer I type in the chat, I get just a blank [] in my file. This means facebook contacts my siete when I try to communicate with the bot, but without any request (data)?

Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Where's the rest of your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook hits your webhook with Content-type `application/json` and JSON string in the request body. *$_REQUEST* cannot handle it because *$_REQUEST* contains the data with HTTP Content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.
Here, you need to read the [input stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) (raw data).

```
<?php
$file = "data.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$data = $current ."\n". file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents ( $file , $data  );
```